# Flutter How to define a single style for MaterialButton widget everywhere in App?

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart

How to define a single style or theme for MaterialButton, FlatButton, RaisedButton widgets everywhere in App.

A style may contain text color, size, font type, corner of circle shape.

```
            child: MaterialButton(
              color: Colors.red,
              onPressed: () {  },
              child: Text(
                'Proceed',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create custom widgets for each. you call it that way.

for example flatButton:

```
class ButtonFlatWidget extends StatelessWidget {
     const ButtonFlatWidget(
     {Key key, @required this.title, @required this.onPress, this.titleColor})
     : super(key: key);

 final String title;
 final Colors titleColor;
 final Function onPress;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FlatButton(
      child: Text(
       title,
       style: TextStyle(color: titleColor ?? Colors.blueAccent, fontSize: 16),
     ),
     onPressed: onPress,
    );
  }
}
```

### then you use the ButtonFlatWidget widget wherever you want.

but I just want to add text color and style. if you say You have to write different methods for each and call them. this is a tough event.

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_charts/charts.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(       
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,       
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,

         buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(
           height:60
           buttonColor: Colors.blueAccent,
           shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(),
           textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.accent,
           ....

        ),
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}
```

- ButtonThemeData.buttonColor: Same as ThemeData.
- ButtonThemeData.splashColor: Same as ThemeData used in FlatButton, OutlineButton or RaisedButton.
- ButtonThemeData.highlightColor: Same as ThemeData.
- ButtonThemeData.hoverColor: Same as ThemeData.
- ButtonThemeData.minWidth: Default minimum width.
- ButtonThemeData.height: Default height.
- ButtonThemeData. padding: Default padding.
- ButtonThemeData.shape: Default shape.
  are some of the common options..